# ARkit HitCube Example, stop updating

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, arkit

Here is the `UnityARHitTestExample.cs` document. My aim is to have the object be placed once (one hit). After that I don't want the object to be moved after the first hit. Any help/suggestions will be helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnityEngine.XR.iOS
{
    public class UnityARHitTestExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform m_HitTransform;
        public float maxRayDistance = 30.0f;
        public LayerMask collisionLayer = 1 << 10;  //ARKitPlane layer

       bool HitTestWithResultType (ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
        {
            List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface ().HitTest (point, resultTypes);
            if (hitResults.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var hitResult in hitResults) {
                    Debug.Log ("Got hit!");
                    m_HitTransform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    m_HitTransform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            #if UNITY_EDITOR   //we will only use this script on the editor side, though there is nothing that would prevent it from working on device
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown ()) {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit hit;

                //we'll try to hit one of the plane collider gameobjects that were generated by the plugin
                //effectively similar to calling HitTest with ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent
                if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, maxRayDistance, collisionLayer)) {
                    //we're going to get the position from the contact point
                    m_HitTransform.position = hit.point;
                    Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));

                    //and the rotation from the transform of the plane collider
                    m_HitTransform.rotation = hit.transform.rotation;

                }

            }
            #else
            if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null)
            {
                var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                    ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
                        x = screenPosition.x,
                        y = screenPosition.y
                    };

                    // prioritize reults types
                    ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
                        // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
                        //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane, 
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                    }; 

                    foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType inresultTypes)
                    {
                        if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
}A
```

Answer (score 0):

create a bool to check if object is placed already.

```
bool placed = false;
```

Execute codes inside `Update()` only if not placed:

```
void Update () {
    if (!placed){
        //code
    }
}
```

now set placed to true after placing object

```
if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
{
    placed = true;
    return;
}
```